# Find the Equation of the Tangent Line to the Curve (Implicit Differentiation)

Tags: calculus

Find the Equation of the Tangent Line to the Curve (A lemniscate) $2(x^2+y^2)^2=25(x^2-y^2)$ at the point $(3,-1)$. The equation of this tangent line can be written in the form $y=mx+b$ where:

$m=$________

$b=$________

My work is in the file attached. I assumed I should factor out the equation first, but maybe that's where I went wrong. [image]

Comment: Observe $2(x^2+y^2)^2=2x^4+4x^2y^2+2y^4$ instead of $2x^4+2y^4$.

Comment: Deriving both sides you get $$2(x^2+y^2)\left(2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=25\left(2x-2y\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$

Comment: You might find parts of this helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785900/points-on-x2-y22-2x2-2y2-with-slope-of-1/785905#785905

Answer (score 1):

Applying Implicit Differentiation, $$2\cdot2(x^2+y^2)\cdot\left(2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=25\cdot\left(2x-2y\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$

So, at $(3,-1)$ it reduces to $$80\left(3-\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=50\left(3+\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$